How to enable Http/3 in .net8 app in a Linux Container on Azure Kubernetes
I'm trying to enable http3 in a .net8 app . I've followed the instructions in the following document

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/http3?view=aspnetcore-8.0

where the kestrel server is as follows
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) => {
    options.ListenAnyIP(5001, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2AndHttp3;
        listenOptions.UseHttps();
    }); });

Also the docker container looks something like this
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "Presentation/Web.WeatherApi.csproj"
WORKDIR "/src/Presentation/Web.WeatherApi"
RUN dotnet build "Web.WeatherApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build --no-restore

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Web.WeatherApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish --no-restore

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Web.WeatherApi.dll"]
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

When running locally i can see HTTP/3 but on deploying the app in Kubernetes through the container, in the logs I still see HTTP/2
Am i missing something in the dockerfile
